# Problems with pip and torch when installing Stable Diffusion

Tags: python-3.x, pip, pytorch, stable-diffusion

I have tried to install stable diffusion to a new computer that did not previously have python on it. I followed the instructions exactly including creating the PATH and installing 3.10.6, but it is still giving me the "no module named pip" and "couldn't install torch error". Please help!

It's worth noting that I downloaded python to the local C drive, but have stable diffusion folder on drive E. I'm not sure if this an issue, beccause when I tried to download python to the E drive, it gave me an the same " no module named pip" and immediately exited.

Here is what I have from my command

`venv "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\venv\\Scripts\\Python.exe" Python 3.10.6 (main, Dec 22 2022, 15:39:53) \[MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)\] Version: v1.6.0 Commit hash: 5ef669de080814067961f28357256e8fe27544f4 Installing torch and torchvision E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe: No module named pip Traceback (most recent call last): File "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\launch.py", line 48, in \<module\> main() File "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\launch.py", line 39, in main prepare_environment() File "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\modules\\launch_utils.py", line 352, in prepare_environment run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch", live=True) File "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\modules\\launch_utils.py", line 115, in run raise RuntimeError("\\n".join(error_bits)) RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch. Command: "E:\\A1111\\stable-diffusion-webui\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe" -m pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu118 Error code: 1`

`Press any key to continue . . .`

I'm not sure whether to download pip? I've re-downloaded and uninstalled pip several times, as well as restarted the computer. I'd reallly appreciate some help, Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

Go to stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts folder and open python.exe and use the following code

import ensurepip
ensurepip.bootstrap()

Comment: `venv\Scripts\python.exe -m ensurepip` is enough.